# Two dates are equal from date field of two model in django

Tags: django

My template where I am checking two dates from two model are equal:

```
sittings.sit_date = '{{ sittings.sit_date }}'<br>
shiftdates.shift_date = '{{ shiftdates.shift_date }}'<br>

    {% if sittings.sit_date == shiftdates.sit_date %}
        <p>Equal on {{shiftdates.sit_date}}
    {% else %}
        Not Equal
    {% endif %}
```

Here Sitting model are linked with Shiftdate model as a foreign key.

This gave output:

```
Logo sittings.sit_date = ''
shiftdates.shift_date = ''  

 Equal on
```

Here you see no dates was shown.

How to show which dates are equal of two fields?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just asking, Why are you setting the dates with date + <br>). Pass only the date to the template, compare them there, and render whateever you want with your <br> element...

Comment: Just see the two dates in two lines.  I set date field to template but not showing the date value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of this problem. Templates code need some changes. Here is my solution:

```
{% for shift in shiftdates %}
        {% if sittings.sit_date == shiftdates.sit_date %}
            <p>Firstly it was scheduled on {{shift.sit_date.sit_date}}</p>
        {% else %}
            Not Equal
        {% endif %}
    <p>Then Shifted to: {{ shift.shift_date }}</p>
```

{% endfor %}